# How to move labelled Gmail in the Trash back to labelled folders instead of to the Inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

How to move labelled Gmail in the Trash back to but *back into* the labelled folders instead of to the Inbox?

Comment: when looking in the trash do the messages still have all the expected labels?

Answer (score 1):

When you send a message to the Trash in Gmail, the message still retains its any labels that were assigned to it.

[image]

In the photo, the email has a label "Apple."

Clicking the `x` button next to the Trash label will move it back into your inbox, in addition to the original labels.

[image]

To move it back to the original labels and skip the inbox, you need to click `Move To` and then the folder you want to move it back to. This will skip the inbox step.

[image]